# How to pass a validator to a inputtext in a nested(!) composite component in JSF 2

Tags: jsf, nested, validation, custom-component

I have the following problem with nested composite components and passing validators to a inputtext in a nested component:

The wrapper custom component (**wrapper.xhtml**):

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="false" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputLabel value="TEST:"/>
        <temptest:input value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
            <cc:insertChildren/>
        </temptest:input>
    </h:panelGroup>
</cc:implementation>
```

The nested custom component (**input.xhtml**):

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="false" />
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="input" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="input" >
        <cc:insertChildren/>
    </h:inputText>
</cc:implementation>
```

The trial to pass a validator to the nested custom component (**pageXYZ.xhtml**):

```
<h:form>
...
    <temptest:wrapper value="#{bean.value}">
        <f:validateRequired for="input"/>
    </temptest:wrapper>
    <!-- this works:
    <temptest:input value="#{bean.value}"> 
        <f:validateRequired for="input"/>
    </temptest:input> -->
    <h:message for="input"/>
...
</h:form>
```

Is there a way to pass (one or more) validators to a nested custom component?